# magento 2 checkout whats is config & deps?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3

Does anyone know about config & deps in checkout like below code -

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
                  <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.billing-step.payment</item>
      </item>
</item>
```

Comment: @MuhammadHasham sorry to say this,but still i am not fully understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load testchild component before testchildtwo then you should configure it in xml `config` node. Inside `config` node we have to define node . `Deps` node is array and can contains more that one component. In our case we defined only one component checkout.testchild.

```
<item name="deps" xsi:type="array"> 
     <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.testchild</item> 
</item>
```

Deps name must contain full component name, in our case it is: checkout.testchild. Our component depends to component checkout.testchild.

Reference: https://potkoc.com/2018/11/10/magento-2-ui-components-dependency/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i will just do upvote,i will not accept answer until fully understand